# How to use data passed via jQuery Sortable in Codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to use [jQuery UI Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) to re-arrange some items in an HTML list. I've got it functioning, but I'm stuck on how to use the data.

I am using Codeigniter and I am passing the order via serial to the `update_order` method in my Category controller.

I know how I'm going to enter it into the database, but I'm not sure how to use the serial so that I can do it. I'm assuming it's in a POST variable of some sort, but I don't know what it is.

The JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#order").sortable({
        update : function () {
            order = $('#order').sortable('serialize');
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?=base_url().'admin/category/update_order'?>",
                type: "POST",
                data: order,
                success: function(){
                    alert("success");
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
);
</script>
```

The HTML:

```
<ul id="order">
    <li id="item_1">Item 1</li>
    <li id="item_2">Item 2</li>
    <li id="item_3">Item 3</li>
    <li id="item_4">Item 4</li>
    <li id="item_5">Item 5</li>
    <li id="item_6">Item 6</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If doing serialize, do `$this->input->post('item')`

It's going to be whatever is in front of the _1, _2, etc in the li tags.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to save the index of the current element

```
update: function(event, ui) { 
     alert(ui.item.index()); 
}
```

I know you can figure out the rest yourself ;)